# undefined is not an object options.routeGetIdList[action.payload.name]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When navigating to another page it gives an undefined error. Normally no changes have been made.I deleted node_modules and reinstalled. I reset the codes. I deleted the project and restarted. but there was no solution.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'options.routeGetIdList[action.payload.name]')

```
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

````
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.12",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^8.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^9.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.10.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "emoji-regex": "^9.2.1",
    "firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "grapheme-splitter": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.9.2",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-snapchat-login": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
  },```
````

Comment: try to reset the react native cache, react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. It occurred after updating Expo from SDK 39 to 40. Updating react-navigation modules does not solve the problem for me. Starting without cache (expo r -c) should also clear react-native cache but that does not fix the problem, unfortunately. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Okay it seems I have to revert my comment above - I did yet again update all react-navigation dependencies (for me, those were: core, bottom-tabs, drawer, material-top-tabs, native, stack) and now it is working just fine. Maybe give it a try!

Answer (score 7):

Go to `node_modules\@react-navigation\routers\src\StackRouter.tsx`

And do the change as below in line 261 and 368

`options.routeGetIdList` to `options.routeNames`

This fixed my issue

Comment: This isn't a good practice because when you update the package, the updates will be lost. I suggest update version of package.

Comment: @EvertonMirandaDeOliveira, yes. I did update to the latest and still the error was there. That's why I had to change the code. Maybe now it has been fixed. Couldn't check again

Answer (score 5):

The same error was occurring to me when navigating to another screen, to resolve it I just updated the following dependencies to the latest version:

```
@react-navigation/native
```

```
@react-navigation/stack
```

Then I cleared the cache and ran the project:

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated `"@react-navigation/stack"` from `5.1.1` to `5.14.5`. The issue is completely gone for me. Just rm modules, `run npm install`, and `run android build`